# How to access the latest state in the store using createSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga, reselect

This is the first time I'm working with `createSelector`. I am calling an APi that get all blog-posts from an API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.

I have three actions:

```
export const GET_POSTS_FETCH = createAction("GET_POSTS_FETCH");
export const GET_POSTS_SUCCESS = createAction("GET_POSTS_SUCCESS");
export const GET_POSTS_FAIL = createAction("GET_POSTS_FAIL");
```

I have a reducer that is handling the **SUCCESS** and **FAIL** cases, which I created using `createReducer` which upon success successfully adds `return state.posts = action.posts;` or `state.error = action.error;` accordingly, where `state` is initialized with a simple `const globalState = {};`.

Now the issue I'm facing is when I am creating the selectors. So, I have created the following selectors:

```
const allPosts = (state) => state.myReducer.posts;
export const selectPosts = createSelector(allPosts, (posts) => posts);
```

In the UI of my react app I am doing this:

```
const myDispatch = useDispatch();
const retrivedPosts = useSelector(selectPosts); //Doesn't work
// const retrivedPostsThatWorks = useSelector((state) => state.myReducer.posts); //This works

console.log("retrivedPosts: ", retrivedPosts);

useEffect(() => {
  myDispatch(GET_POSTS_FETCH());
}, []);
```

I'm dispatching `GET_POSTS_FETCH` action which in my sagas file getsdata from APi call and upong success the reducer is also storing it accordingly in the store. Now If I take the approach and use `retrivedPostsThatWorks` I can see the data. But I'm not able to achieve it if I call `getAllPosts` which I have created using `createSelector`.

So how do I retrieve the data from a selector created using `createSelector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you don't have the full path in the `allPosts` function. Try to replace this:

```js
const allPosts = (state) => state.posts;
```

with:

```js
const allPosts = (state) => state.myReducer.posts;
```

**Update:**

Second issue that you have in your codesandbox is your reducer, specifically this part:

```
.addCase(GET_POSTS_SUCCESS, (state, action) => {
  return (state.posts = action.posts);
})
```

You should either modify the state or return a new one, but you can't do both. So e.g. simply removing the return will do the trick:

```
.addCase(GET_POSTS_SUCCESS, (state, action) => {
  state.posts = action.posts;
})
```

Comment: There is one more problem in the code you sent, I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Not sure why I was doing it like that, maybe I tried something and then forgot to remove it. Anyhow, thank you for catching that :)